# Apex function that returns a map

Tags: apex, apex-webservice

I have to call an external web service, so i created an Apex class to achieve this. However, something seems to go wrong with my return type. I want to return the response from the web service. How could this be achieved?  I get three errors:
[image]
Code below:

```
public class LiveChat {
    
    public static map liveChatCallout(){
       
    
        HTTP h = new HTTP();
        HTTPRequest req = new HTTPRequest();
        
        req.setEndpoint('https://.................');
        req.setMethod('GET');
        
        HTTPResponse res = h.send(req);
        
        Map<String,Object> jsonBody = (Map<String,Object>)Json.deserializeUntyped(res.getBody());
        
        System.debug(jsonBody);
        
        
        return jsonBody;
    }
    
    
}
```

Comment: You missed out the key value pair in your map: `public static Map<String, Object> liveChatCallout()`

Comment: wow, silly mistake! thank you so much Hengky!!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Seems like a minor typo in your method return type declaration.

`public static map liveChatCallout(){ ... }`

to

`public static Map<String,Object> liveChatCallout(){ ... }`